# How to loop a MySQL query and return the result as a single result set ? use function or prcedure?

Tags: mysql, database, function, stored-procedures

I have simple query that returns the count and sum of particular user based on the user id

```
select count(id) links ,sum(download_count) dowloads, user_id from file_list_user where user_id = 6
```

How can I write a function / procedure that loops the same query for all user_id 's?

file_list_user table structure

```
+------+----------------+---------+
| id   | download_count | user_id |
+------+----------------+---------+
|  844 |             20 |       6 |
| 1192 |              4 |       7 |
| 1305 |              1 |       6 |
+------+----------------+---------+
```

The unique user_id's are is stored in another table user

user table structure

```
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | user_name   |
+---------+-------------+
|       6 | clain       |
|       8 | Mayor       |
|       9 | JohnRock    |
+---------+-------------+
```

I have searched through most of the answers in Stack Overflow but none of them addressed my scenario. Some are overly complicated even to understand. I am looking for a simple solution so that I can call this function and return the result as a single result set table similar to below

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| links | dowloads | user_id |
+-------+----------+---------+
|    11 |       36 |       6 |
+-------+----------+---------+
|    15 |       10 |       8 |
+-------+----------+---------+
|    60 |       90 |       9 |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group by` clause instead of `where` clause

```
select count(id) links ,sum(download_count) dowloads, user_id from file_list_user group by user_id
```

Comment: Oh man that was so simple ..!! I did not even think about  group clause my bad..!! I had a hectic day , thanks for the answer.